# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in timestamp issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

In mysql query how i can find which records are changed/updated in 24 hours.

I have mysql table with timestamp with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default.I am using PHP with Mysql.when user edit a record i have a field activitytime with default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,and i want to get all those records which are changed

```
 SELECT * FROM news WHERE activitytime  < 24 hours
```

i tried but no luck

```
 select * from news where activitytime  >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY order by activitytime desc
```

Why my activitytime field do not update which i am updating it?should i save activitytime again?

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crmtbl` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ref` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
`activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=316 ;
```

Query
    mysq_query("INSERT INTO crmtbl(ref) Values('myref')");

mean i am not using activitytime in INSERT OR UPDATE

Comment: Once a default value has been populated it doesn't get updated if the row does, unless you explicitly update that column. What is your update statement? You think you have problems with that as well, so I'm a little confused why you didn't post it originally...

Comment: Does your timestamp field has set "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"?

Comment: activitytime is not updating while i am updating row....here is its structure... `activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Comment: DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -  is only setting current timestamp on INSERT for updating it each time with your row you must set ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ... example :  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: i added explaination to my question and added table structure

Comment: now how i change it to ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: `activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.the_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

you have to make activitytime field on update current timestamp

change that like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crmtbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=316 ;
```

Comment: Sir why my field not updating with row?

Comment: i did it by ALTER TABLE crmtbl MODIFY COLUMN `activitytime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP